Surrealdb.js error fetch failed, how do I fix this?
When I try setting up surreal using, surrealdb.js, I get this error idk aboutenter image description here
import { Surreal } from 'surrealdb.js';

const db = new Surreal();

async function main() {
    try {
        // Connect to the database
        await db.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rpc', {
            // Set the namespace and database for the connection
            namespace: 'test',
            database: 'test',

            // Set the authentication details for the connection
            auth: {
                namespace: 'test',
                database: 'test',
                scope: 'user',
                username: 'root',
                password: 'root',
            },
        });

        // Create a new person with a random id
        const created = await db.create('person', {
            title: 'Founder & CEO',
            name: {
                first: 'Tobie',
                last: 'Morgan Hitchcock',
            },
            marketing: true,
            identifier: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10),
        });

        // Update a person record with a specific id
        const updated = await db.merge('person:jaime', {
            marketing: true,
        });

        // Select all people records
        const people = await db.select('person');

        // Perform a custom advanced query
        const groups = await db.query(
            'SELECT marketing, count() FROM type::table($tb) GROUP BY marketing',
            {
                tb: 'person',
            }
        );
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('ERROR', e);
    }
}

main();

I tried replacing with was at the start of the endpoint, didn’t work aswell. Idk why nothing works, I’ve tried almost everything but nothing seems to work.

The error message indicates that your application is trying to connect to a server at 127.0.0.1:8000 and is getting a ECONNREFUSED error. This usually means that there is no server running on that address and port.
To fix this issue, you need to ensure that the server that surrealdb.js is trying to connect to is running. If the server is supposed to be running on your local machine, make sure it's started and listening on port 8000.
Try setting up a connection using the start command via CLI or on Surrealist
